# The JVM compile class file to assembly source code or binary code

Tags: java, jvm

I wanna know how's jvm compile class file,when JIT compile the class file which handled by jvm,the output is assembly source code or binary executable code.In other words how does JVM compile class files and then what will be to do.
Thanks in advance

Comment: JVM executes .class bytecode. JIT optimizes some of it while your program runs (uses statistics basically) and sometimes it just specializes instructions to use your CPU natives.

Comment: This is a *very* complex and low level subject. How familiar/comfortable are you with assembly and how compilers normally generate assembly code?  Is there a small set of questions you have particular interest in?

Answer (score 0):

These answers are implementation specific ...

The Hotspot JIT compilers don't compile to assembler source code.  Rather it emits native code instructions directly into memory ready to be executed.

Depending on the Hotpot version, JVM switches and so on, JIT compilation happens after the JVM has executed a method a few times using the bytecode interpreter.  In recent JVMs, statistics are gathered during the initial interpretation phase which then help the JIT compiler to generate better code.